# Custom library written with Nest usage within React project

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, logic, nest

I have a very complex lib that does logic, I wrote it with Nest.
There's lots of injectable services with modules, that fetch staff and do more logic.
Currently there is a route to access the lib logic.
Now I want to do this logic within the UI, without the server.
Is it possible to import the lib within my React project? Or is refactoring the lib shell be the solution?

I have started to refractor the code, removing the Nest parts will be a big mess.

Comment: You can import specific files

Comment: It will not help, I have tones of dependencies for each file